# Wordpress Multisite - Domain mapping || Second domain gets redirected to first domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, mapping

ok, after many, many hours of trying around and reading tutorials, i slowly start to understand. But not yet completely.

I have successfully managed to turn my existing (german) wordpress installation (**site1.de**) into a multisite. I want to create a second blog (english), which would run through **site2.de**.

So, german blog under **site1.de**.

I've added a new wordpress site ("test") which corresponds to **site1.de/test**. It works.

In the "Network admin", the "Domain mapping" points to "**site1.de**" (I don't have an IP).

In the "test" admin area, I click on "Domain mapping", "add new domain" and enter **site2.de**, as primary domain.

Now, there is something I have to do on the webhosting administration side. I can change the domain attribution, so that **site2.de** gets redirected to **site1.de**.

But when I do this, my **site2.de** get's indeed redirected to **site1.de**, but not **site1.de/test**. And **site1.de/test** gets redirected to **site1.de**.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it. The second domain must be "redirected" to the PATH of the first domain, not the URL. That's it...